# Metro: 2033 and Last Light Tags

Tags: discussion, tags

Looking through my own tags, I noticed I had a tag for [metro-2033-redux](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metro-2033-redux) . Looking through other Metro tags, there are only 3:

- [metro-2033](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metro-2033)
- [metro-last-light](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metro-last-light)
- [metro-2033-redux](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metro-2033-redux)

Do we want to keep questions about those games to just the first two tags, or is it wise to create Redux tags for the questions, depending on which version the asker is playing?

Comment: I think there are slight differences between the redux versions and the original. I believe I remember following a guide that mentioned that certain moral points only exist in the redux versions (as an example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [this list of changes for Metro Last Light Redux](http://metrovideogame.wikia.com/wiki/Metro_Last_Light_Redux), I'd say a new [metro-last-light-redux](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metro-last-light-redux) tag would be appropriate, mostly due to the following parts:

> Some areas have been changed or had areas added
>
> Spartan and Survival mode
>
> New achievement/trophy list

Different areas *seems* like a big enough difference to warrant a new tag if a question about an altered area comes up. New gameplay modes and achievements/trophies are also a decent case for a new tag.

---

As for the [metro-2033-redux](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metro-2033-redux) tag, this is **definitely** necessary, as the changes are much more drastic, as seen [here](http://metrovideogame.wikia.com/wiki/Metro_2033_Redux):

> Some levels have been expanded such as the Dead City section, which is now a single level.
>
> Certain characters and items have new locations
>
> Diary entries, such as to the ones in Last Light, can be found on each level
>
> Metro 2033 Redux will gain some weapons from Last Light and its DLCs
>
> Spartan and Survival mode
>
> New achievement/trophy list

The Redux edition of Metro 2033 adds previously unavailable content and switches up locations of characters and items, which definitely warrants a new tag.

Comment: Sounds good to me!